# Mapping to replace \newfont with \usefont

Tags: fonts

Rather than write

```
\newfont{\mynewfont}{pagk8r scaled 3000}
```

one now apparently (Ref.: [Math symbol within a new-font word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118496/math-symbol-within-a-new-font-word)) should write:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\bigavantgarde{\fontsize{30}{42}\usefont{\encodingdefault}{pag}{m}{n}}
```

What is the general mapping?

In other words, for a given font in my

> /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map

, say `pagko8r`, what is the mapping to use `\usefont` instead of `\newfont`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"now" meaning any time since around 1993 I assume? as this hasn't changed in latex2e.

If you just need a LaTeX interface to a fixed font without setting all the usual font axis commands, then an alternative would be

```
\DeclareFixedFont\bigavantgarde\encodingdefault}{pag}{m}{n}{30}
```

The mapping between the LaTeX font axis view and external font files is managed via the declarations in `fd` files for example the file `t1pag.fd` is loaded if using `pag` in T1 encoding and has, amongst its declarations

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pag}{m}{n}{
   <-> pagk8t
}{}
```

Which says that at all sizes, the font to use for `{T1}{pag}{m}{n}` is a suitably scaled version of `pagk8t.tfm` .

Comment: I was hoping there would be a more direct way than searching through all .fd files in my distribution, but it works just fine.

Comment: @Calaf And  where did you get `pagk8r`? Which, by the way, uses a rather peculiar encoding.

Comment: @egreg .. by peeking at texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/avantgar/*.tfm and neighbors. Can you suggest a friendlier method?

Comment: @Calaf `texdoc psnfss` for the "35 fonts".